# How to pick image from particular folder, say sdcard/mypics?

Tags: android

How to pick image from particular folder, say sdcard/mypics?

Answer (score 0):

i can recommend the [gridview tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html).

you will have to modify the code a bit to get the resource into an array before showing the gridview. but therefore you can use the [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile%28java.lang.String%29)  class.

Comment: hope that fits your question.